# How to Parse Binary .STL File Created on Ancient 32-bit Architecture

Tags: import, numerical-value, machine-precision, binary, order

Import[fileName,"STL"] returns $Failed
The file format is so simple that one can calculate the number of triangles in the file
by counting the number of BinaryReads to reach EndOfFile.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

However, UINT32 value beginning at byte 81 in the file is supposed to be Number of triangles.  Behold:

```
numTriangles = 
 BinaryRead[inFileStream, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1]
```

2,056,599,864 -- Exceeds FileSize[fileName]

```
In[30]:= ImportByteArray[ExportByteArray[numTriangles, "Integer32"]]

Out[30]= {56, 57, 149, 122}

In[31]:= ImportByteArray[ExportByteArray[17616, "Integer32"]]

Out[31]= {208, 68, 0, 0}
```

Where 17616 is the value of the loop counter after reading subsequent 50-byte triangles
following the Number-of-Triangles UINT32 value.  It looks to me that no combination of byte-ordering will make the Number-of-Triangles value equal the actual number of triangles stored in the file.  The file was almost certainly created on an MC68000-series 32-bit processor in either a Silicon Graphics Iris 2400/3000-series, a Sun-3 workstation or possibly an IBM PC (x86?) of the same era.

How does one go about parsing such a binary file as this?  Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article says the number-of-triangles UINT32 is little-endian, so why are you specifying ByteOrdering->1, which is big-endian? (Unfortunately, this won’t fix your problem, but it seems wrong.)

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: In[165]:= numTriangles=BinaryRead[inFileStream,"Integer32", ByteOrdering->-1]
Out[165]= -1091561984 seems more wrong than big-endian. In[166]:= ImportByteArray[ExportByteArray[numTriangles, "Integer32"]]

Out[166]= {0, 22, 240, 190}

In[167]:= ImportByteArray[ExportByteArray[17616, "Integer32"]]

Out[167]= {208, 68, 0, 0}

Comment: @MarcoB, Here's a ZIP file of such examples in Google Drive.  Thanks! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxmT0KzwtZtIgiru2ru8OkppAlC-jjP7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Stewart Check access permissions on that link. It currently returns an "access denied" error.

Comment: OK, try it now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxmT0KzwtZtIgiru2ru8OkppAlC-jjP7/view?usp=sharing